# Finding sides of a triangle

Tags: trigonometry

I have the question:

[image]

[image]

Here is my attempt is this correct ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RQ is obviously longer than $13.8$. It says to use the Sine Rule but from the known values it makes more sense to use the Cosine Rule.

$a^2 = 13.8^2 + 4.8^2 - (2\cdot 13.8\cdot 4.8 \cdot \cos(135))$

$ a = \sqrt(307.1575) = 17.5259$

And $y = \frac{13.8}{\sqrt 2} = 9.7581$

Comment: Thank you so much :)